# How to make possible to deselect text in a Text component in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make an app with React Native which shows a lot of information to the end user.
It's vital that the user can select/copy/paste the info from and to the app.

The `selectable` property of `Text` is quite useful since it uses the native android UI for selecting text.

My only problem is that if you select a part of the text (intentionally or accidentally), you can only deselect if you tap inside the Text component again.
That is, if I touch the screen anywhere else (where any other component would be, even its father), the text keeps being selected.

Take, for example, the "Hello World" in React Native Documentation, and just add the selectable property:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function YourApp() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Text selectable>
        Try editing me! 
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

If you run it on android, you'll notice that you can indeed select and copy when you double tap (or long tap) as expected. But you won't be able to cancel the selection unless you tap on some part of the text again. If you touch any other part of the screen the selection UI won't go away.

Is there a way to achieve that? There are too many `Text` components in my app, with varying length and size. When users accidentally select something, a lot feel frustrated tapping away and nothing happening.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would use a TouchableWithoutFeedback component.

[TouchableWithoutFeedback](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html)

Example from RN, where alert('Pressed!') is your function to remove selection.

```js
function MyComponent(props) {
  return (
    <View {...props} style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
      <Text>My Component</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => alert('Pressed!')}>
  <MyComponent />
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>;
```

Comment: Could you provide what would the function to remove selection be?
That's actually what I want to know

Comment: OnPress doesn't removes the selected text